# Testing custom constraints in Grails App

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, constraints

I have the following as my unit test:

```
void testCreateDealer() {
      mockForConstraintsTests(Dealer)
      def _dealer= new Dealer( dealerName:"ABC",
                            Email:"abc-motors@global.com",
                            HeadOffice:"",
                            isBranch:false)
       assertFalse _dealer.validate()

    }
```

But when I run the test I get the following error:

```
No signature of method: static com.myCompany.Dealer.findByDealerNameIlike() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ABC]
```

I use some custom constraints in my domain class. How Can I test this?

```
 static constraints = {
     dealerName(blank:false, validator:
            { val, obj ->
                      def similarDealer = Dealer.findByDealerNameIlike(val)
                      return !similarDealer || (obj.id == similarDealer.id)
            }
     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing mockForConstraintsTests() to mockDomain() - you're using a Dealer.findX() method in the constraint, which relies on the Dealer domain.

Incidentally, the test will still fail unless you've created a similar dealer in the setUp() method of the test class.

Comment: Thanks Ali
I modified my code and did some research on mockDomain.
I changed my code to:
http://wb.pastebin.com/g1jCwVAM

But still the validation is not kicking in.

Please let me know if I am missing something here

Much Appreciated.

Comment: Hi WaZ, I'm not familiar with this use of mockForConstraintsTest.  mockDomain() should set up the constraint testing.  The following passes: http://pastebin.com/w4mHmFH0

Answer (score 0):

In unit tests, even with mockDomain, the id attribute of domain objects is not set automatically, or auto-incremented.  All of the domain objects you create will have an id of `null` unless you explicitly set it.

Your test is probably failing because the test `obj.id == similarDealer.id` is true, since they both have `id: null`.  Try setting the id attribute of your mocked dealer objects.

Comment: not sure, because it does seem to work without me to implement the auto increment.